# Is there a way to test an AppLifecycleState change in a Flutter unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, flutter

My app writes user preferences to a local file when the app is moved to the background (AppLifecycleState.paused) and I'd like to write a test for this behavior.

Is there a way to mimic this in a unit test?  Or is this something that would need to be done as an integration test?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can call `binding.handleAppLifecycleStateChanged` to fake the app going in and out of the foreground in a unit test.

Comment: You can get your binding with "final binding = TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();".

Answer (score 8):

`tester.binding.handleAppLifecycleStateChanged` is definitly the correct way to test it.

ex: Statefull widget on the home page that listen to app lifecycle

```
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      pushLoginPage(context);
    }
  }
```

If you want to test this, you have to `paused` first, and then `resumed` to ensure Flutter navigation.